# how to do conditional logic in gtsummary?

Tags: r, gtsummary

[I get this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fr1A.png)

```
#Creating the dataframe

data <- data.frame(
  alive = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1),
  reason = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "pneumonia", "stillbirth", "", "", "", ""),
  baby_ill = c(2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1),
  episode = c("", "", "", 3, "", 4, 4, "", "", "", "", "")
)

# Convert character columns to factors
data[] <- lapply(data, as.factor)

# Create gtsummary table
tbl_summary(data) %>% add_n()
```

[Desired output]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3ocg.png)

Comment: You convert all the data.frame to factors, no only characters, would this affect the output?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68874118/3460670) may be helpful, though a bit involved.